# How to Split a big file 32 GB or more using C?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code which reads a file but small file size and split them into smaller files. I want to make this code read big size file like 32 GB or more and support different kind of data type files hopefully  looking for answer to help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    FILE *ptr_readfile;
    FILE *ptr_writefile;
    char line [128]; /* or some other suitable maximum line size */
    char fileoutputname[15];
    int filecounter=1, linecounter=1;

    ptr_readfile = fopen("editing for the java lab 2.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_readfile)
        return 1;

    sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d", filecounter);
    ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr_readfile)!=NULL) {
        if (linecounter == 5) {
            fclose(ptr_writefile);
            linecounter = 1;
            filecounter++;
            sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d", filecounter);
            ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
            if (!ptr_writefile)
                return 1;
        }
        fprintf(ptr_writefile,"%s\n", line);
        linecounter++;
    }
    fclose(ptr_readfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't care about file types. It reads and writes binary.

Comment: FYI: If you're on Linux/BSD/Cygwin, there's already a split-command available

Comment: First thing I notice you are needlessly mean with `char fileoutputname[15];`. Make it `80`.

Comment: You've described what you want to do but you haven't actually asked a specific question. What is specifically  it that is preventing you from writing the code?

Comment: There is no reason that this would not work for larger files, you are always only reading up to 128 bytes, so the RAM usage does not scale with files size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first the file type has absolutly no importance. In C you read a file as it is, directly in binary. Everything (except folders, I'm not sure, and some exception maybe) in Windows are files, even executables.

Then the size is not really a problem, if you read it step by step with a "small" buffer (like what you are doing), there will be no problem.

So you could do, after every 10 buffer, you write in a new file, until the end of the one you read. There is not really a problem or question here.

Just some details, your buffer size should be `4096` for performances on big files. 4096 should be the most optimized size, at least with the read() function, I dunno for fget().

Then your filename size shoud be `256`. 255 is the max filename size on most OS (256 with the nullbyte).